# App store connect user but not developer?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

My client added me to appstoreconnect as an App Manager and Developer, but I still can't make builds in Xcode, and can't see my new developer team.

I don't think the client's developer account is an organization.

Is there any way I can archive builds in xcode on his behalf without getting his account credentials?

Comment: Hi @xytor. Did you find any way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

When You can see Your client's name in AppStore Connect (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com), but not on Apple Developer portal (https://developer.apple.com), this means that Your client created his account as an **Individual**.

To check his account type, client should go to his developer account, and then check the `Entity type` in the [`Membership`](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/) section:

[image: Apple Developer portal - Membership tab]

After he confirms that his `Entity type` is set to **Individual**, he can request to change it in **one** of the following ways:

#### 1 - [Contact us - Individual to Organization Membership Update](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/?entityType=individual&requestType=migrateAccount) - recommended way

Go to [this contact form (linked above)](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/?entityType=individual&requestType=migrateAccount) and fill in all the data (Region, Name, Website, D-U-N-S Number etc.). You can get to this form "manually" by clicking `Need to edit this information?` in the bottom right corner of the `Membership` section. I would **recommend** You to use this form, because Apple then won't have to contact You for any of the Organization's information after Your submission.

#### 2 - [Contact us - submit page](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/) - alternative way

Go to [this contact form (linked above)](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/), select `Account updates and renewals` and in the `Message` field write something similar to this:

```
I’d like to convert my account from Individual to Organization.
This will be our only Organization account.

Here are the information regarding the company:

CEO/Director Name: First and Last Name.
Company Name: Your Company Name, including Ltd or Inc.
Account Type: Organization.
D-U-N-S Number: your Company’s DUNS number.
Address: Your Company’s Legal Address.
Phone Number: Your mobile phone or another phone number where you can be reached
```

According to [this Quora answer](https://qr.ae/TWTB71), transition process can take around **7 days** to complete, so be patient. :)

Comment: My Client's membership type is company/organization and I am facing this problem still. any solution?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz what is exactly your problem? You can see the entity type but cannot make build archives? Did the company add you as a developer?

Comment: My team is not showing in developer.apple.com and XCode but is showing in App Store Connect. I cannot sign my app because the team is not there in the Drop down menu

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz are you sure you are added to that team? Did you accept the invite?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz maybe this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389407/2101117

Comment: Yes I accepted the invite. This was automatically resolved after 2 - 3 days. Looks like a bug from Apple

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz okay, glad it was sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question, your client needs to add you in [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/), not just in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/).

To simplify things a bit, **iTunes Connect** only allows you to submit apps to the App Store while **Apple Developer** allows you to create certificates and provisioning profiles, sign apps, and distribute development and ad-hoc builds.

Comment: But he's not an organization, just a developer. There is no way to add users.