# Team is not showing in developer.apple.com but showing in the app store connect

Tags: app-store-connect, membership, apple-developer

I have admin role of an account and able to view the team in app store connect website but with the same account not able to view the same on developer.apple.com. Did't get what is going wrong here.

[image]

> Update : Adding a user from developer.apple.com, redirect to the appstore connect. It means now there is no difference between developer.apple.com user and app store connect users.

[image]

Comment: I think this is just a bug. Try to login with another browser

Comment: already tries a lot of time, but no success.

Comment: I am experiencing the same, any luck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

App Store Connect team is different and Developer.apple.com access is different.

You have admin role on App Store Connect but not on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com)

Ask the owner of the account to give you access on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com)

Your client needs to add you in [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com)

**App Store Connect** only and only allows you to submit your apps to the App Store while **Apple Developer** allows you to create your certificates and provisioning profiles, sign your apps, and distribute development and ad-hoc builds.

Comment: If m going to add a member from developer.apple.com, its redirecting me to the app store connect website, please check my update on question. It shows now there is no difference between both users.

Comment: do you have individual account ?

Comment: To check his account type, client should go to his developer account, and then check the Entity type in the Membership section

Comment: oh, I think client have individual account. mine is company account.

Comment: yup .. thats the issue ... thank you :) happy coding ... 
you can follow this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/55725699/1780632

Comment: I got reply from Apple support and you were correct.

Comment: yeah ...  its like that

Answer (score 2):

Finally got reply from Apple support.

[image]

Comment: They may have been pointing at this link: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devdbefef011

Comment: The actual solution might be: You have to have been granted "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" . See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54679267/28037

Answer (score 1):

Right now, If your account type is 'Individual' instead of 'Organization', you can't add another person to your developer account (but you can add anyone on appstore connect).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have admin access but the team was being shown only in developer and not in appstore connect.

My solution was to select the team in Developer Account and from there you see a button to go to AppStore Connect.

After clicking the button teams were in sync.